# delete names columns from dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I crate a dataframe from iris.csv file :

raw_data = pd.read_csv("iris.csv", header=0)

`raw_data` :

```
Species     Sepal.Length    Sepal.Width     Petal.Length    Petal.Width
0   setosa  5.1     3.5     1.4     0.2
1   setosa  4.9     3.0     1.4     0.2
2   setosa  4.7     3.2     1.3     0.2
3   setosa  4.6     3.1     1.5     0.2
4   setosa  5.0     3.6     1.4     0.2
5   setosa  5.4     3.9     1.7     0.4
6   setosa  4.6     3.4     1.4     0.3
7   setosa  5.0     3.4     1.5     0.2
8   setosa  4.4     2.9     1.4     0.2
```

Then I  extract the first column in a data frame ;

```
train_y = raw_data.ix[:,0]
```

`train_y` :

```
0         setosa
1         setosa
2         setosa
3         setosa
4         setosa
5         setosa
6         setosa
7         setosa
8         setosa
9         setosa
10        setosa
```

But when I try to extract the train_X composed from other columns :

```
train_X = raw_data.ix[:,1:]
```

I get columns names too
Is there any way to delete nams columns from train_X

thanks

Comment: did you mean you want to get rid of  `Sepal.Length    Sepal.Width     Petal.Length    Petal.Width` ?

Comment: yes this what i am looking for

Comment: I think you want to extract values, hence can use this `raw_data.ix[:,1:].values`

more details,  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html

Answer (score 0):

To get the data, try this:

```
train_X = raw_data.iloc[:, 1:]
```

Comment: hello, same thing

Comment: You could try to import the data without the column names: `raw_data = pd.read_csv("iris.csv", header=False)`

Comment: It not true : got this error : TypeError: Passing a bool to header is invalid. Use header=None for no header or header=int or list-like of ints to specify the row(s) making up the column names